# Sitecore Error: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler. No matching constructor was found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Has anyone ran into the issue below? Basically, I am trying to upgrade the Web forms for Marketers from 8.0-U3 to 8.0-U4(successful) to 8.1-Initial release (not successful).

The error was during the update installation process:
http://upgrade/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx

It says:

> The installation has encountered a critical error.
>
> > This Sitecore installation cannot be used for either testing or
> >     production purposes until Sitecore support is contacted. Make sure to
> >     download and include the file containing diagnostic information about
> >     your Sitecore installation.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler. No matching constructor was found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler. No matching constructor was found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler. No matching constructor was found.]
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +272
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +131
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.Add(String eventName, XmlNode configNode) +545
   Sitecore.Events.Event.GetConfigSubscribers() +564
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +338
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.SetProperty(String parameterName, String value, CallContext context) +259
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.SetProperty(String name, String value, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +124
   Sitecore.Data.DataManager.SetProperty(String name, String value) +103
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.TicketManager.IsTicketExpired(Ticket ticket, Boolean useProlongation) +330
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.TicketManager.GetTicket(String ticketId, Boolean returnExpired) +93
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.TicketManager.IsTicketValid(String ticketId) +37
   Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin) +409
   Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.SecurePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +22
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fixed the issue. I reinstalled the update package of WFFM 8.1. But prior to that, I copy and pasted the DLLs and configuration files of WFFM 8.1-Initial release to my instance before undergoing under run of update.

**Edited**: Root cause, forgot to update the **Sitecore.Forms.config** with the patch below:

```
<handler type="Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler, Sitecore.Forms.Core" method="OnWffmActionEventFired" > 
<param name="actionManager" ref="/sitecore/wffm/wffmActionExecutor" /> </handler>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had fixed by copying entire DLL from clean-sitecore installation folder, When more dig on it who is black sheep is below they are

1. Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll
2. Sitecore.Forms.Custom.dll
3. Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll

Above dll's version differed.